# SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quisiera combinar una destructuración con un mapa en python para procesar pares de columnas de una lista de datos.

Mi solución ideal sería algo como

```
def openOrSenior(data):
  return list(map(lambda [age, handicap]: 'Senior' if (age>54 and handicap>7) else 'Open', data))
```

La solución al problema sin destructuración que tengo es

```
def openOrSenior(data):
    return list(map(lambda arr: 'Senior' if (arr[0]>54 and arr[1]>7) else 'Open', data))
```

Para lograrlo se me ocurrió esto:

```
def openOrSenior(data):
  return list(map(lambda arr: 'Senior' if (age>54 and handicap>7) else 'Open' for (age, handicap) in arr, data))
```

pero me produce un error que no logro entender.

> SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument

Gracias a abulafia se corrigió el error pero me sigue pareciendo un desperdicio comparado con mi solución ideal.

```
def openOrSenior(data):
  return sum(list(map(lambda arr: list('Senior' if (age>54 and handicap>7) else 'Open' for (age, handicap) in [arr]), data)),[])
```

ante esto me surgen las siguientes dudas: ¿Por que me detecta un generador si no tengo `yield return`? ¿hay una forma de lograr mi solución ideal?

Comment: Hola Ruslan, no necesitas `yield` para crear un generador, hay otras formas de hacerlo usando tuplas de comprensión, tal vez Python esté pensando que quieres hacer eso. ¿Podrías dar un ejemplo de tu input y tu output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un generador puede crearse usando una función que contenga un `yield`, pero también puede ser retornado por otras funciones estándar de python como `range()`, `map()`y otras.

También (y esto es relevante aquí) mediante lo que se llama una "expresión generadora" (*generator expression*), que son similares a las *list comprehensions* pero con paréntesis en vez de corchetes. Por ejemplo:

```py
>>> numeros = range(10)                   # numeros es un generador
>>> cuadrados = (x**2 for x in numeros)   # cuadrados es otro generador
```

Ninguno de los generadores ha producido aún ningún dato. Comenzarán a producirlos cuando los evaluemos en un bucle, como por ejemplo:

```py
>>> for x in cuadrados:
...   pass
```

Entonces el generador `cuadrados` será ejecutado, y eso causará también la ejecución del generador `numeros` (el cual a su vez causa la ejecución del generador retornado por `range()`.

Una función puede recibir un generador como parámetro. Por ejemplo la función `sum()` que itera sobre los elementos devueltos por el generador y los va sumando todos. Así:

```py
>>> sum(cuadrados)
285
```

Una vez "agotado" el generador, no puede volver a usarse (no "contiene" ya más elementos)

```py
>>> sum(cuadrados)
0
```

A la función que admite un generador como parámetro, podemos pasarle la expresión generadora, como aqui:

```py
>>> sum( (x**2 for x in range(10)) )
285
```

Fíjate en el doble paréntesis. Tenemos unos paréntesis para delimitar el argumento de `sum()` y otros para delimitar la expresión generadora. Cuando no hay ambigüedad posible (es decir, cuando la expresión generadora es el único argumento que le estoy pasando), se pueden omitir estos paréntesis internos. Así:

```py
>>> sum(x**2 for x in range(10))
285
```

Sin embargo, si la función admite más de un parámetro y queremos pasar ambos, ya no puedo omitir los paréntesis alrededor de la función generadora. Por ejemplo, `sum()` admite un segundo parámetro opcional con el valor inicial de la suma. Entonces lo llamaría así:

```py
>>> sum((x**2 for x in range(10)), 100)
385
```

Si omito los paréntesis en la expresión generadora, obtengo una excepción:

```py
>>> sum(x**2 for x in range(10), 100)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument
```

¿Te suena este mensaje de error? Ahora ya sabes qué tenías mal ;-)

## Actualización

Buscando aproximarme a la "solución ideal" buscada por el usuario, y teniendo en cuenta que Python 3 ha eliminado el *unpacking* de los argumentos de una `lambda` (también conocido como *desestructuración*), lo más cercano sería lo siguiente:

```py
def openOrSenior(data):
  return list(map(lambda p: (
                  lambda age, handicap: 'Senior' if (age>54 and handicap>7) else 'Open'
                  )(*p), data))
```

Como ves el truco consiste en encerrar tu `lambda` ideal en otra lambda que recibe un único parámetro `p`, y a la que llamo inmediatamente pasándole `*p`. Ese asterisco causa la expansión de la tupla `p`, y lo que llega a la `lambda` interna son los dos valores que buscabas.

Sigue sin ser la solución ideal, pero para mi gusto es mejor que el "desperdicio" que supone el generador interno y el `sum` posterior.

En cualquier caso, python poco a poco ha ido huyendo de este tipo de sintaxis, en favor de las *list comprehensions*. Usando una de estas tu función quedaría así:

```py
def openOrSenior(data):
    return ['Senior' if (age>54 and handicap>7) else 'Open'
             for (age, handicap) in data]
```

Infinitamente más legible para mi gusto.